# how to delete an item from dynamoDB using CURL command?

Tags: javascript, curl, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I was trying to modify items inside DynamoDB using curl command. Here are the table data types: **email(primary key)**, **name**, **phone**. I was able to PUT an item to DynamoDB, GET all data for a single item, and DELETE all data in a single item using the following CURL commands.

**POST an item**: `curl -v -X "PUT" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"email\": \"random_email@email.com\", \"name\": \"Mr. X\", \"phone\": \"1111111111\"}" aws_api_link/items`

**GET all data**:`curl -v aws_api_link/items`

**DELETE all data**: `curl -v -X "DELETE" aws_api_link/items/random_email@email.com`

Now I am trying to DELETE a specific data in the item. For example, if an item in table has the following data, *email: random_email@email.com, name: Mr. X, phone: 1111111111*, I want to delete only the phone number and not touch other data. Updated data would be email: *random_email@email.com, name: Mr. X, phone: (empty)*. The code I am expecting to work would be like:
`curl -v -X "DELETE" aws_api_link/items/random_email@email.com/1111111111` 
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You need to update the item with an empty phone number, use update rather than delete

Comment: that is an idea. It works that way as temporary solution. But i'll wait to see if there is a delete solution.